# TwythonStreamer: OR does not work as a filter

Tags: python, api, twitter, twython

I'm not sure why the following code does not return any result. If I put `streamer.statuses.filter(track = 'data')`, then it outputs tweets. However, if I use `join` with `OR`, it does not work, though I am using `'data'` as one of options. Finally, if I use `track=keywords`, it neither works.

```
from twython import TwythonStreamer
from collections import Counter

tweets = []

class TweetStreamer(TwythonStreamer):
    def on_success(self, data):
        if 'text' in data:
            tweets.append(data['text'].encode('utf-8'))
            print data['text'].encode('utf-8')
        if len(tweets)>10:
            self.disconnect()

    def on_error(self, status_code, data):
        print status_code
        self.disconnect()

CONSUMER_KEY = "..."
CONSUMER_SECRET = "..."
ACCESS_TOKEN = "..."
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = "..."

streamer = TweetStreamer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,
                         ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

keywords = ['data','information']
track = " OR ".join(keywords)

streamer.statuses.filter(track = track)
```

Comment: Mmh i think you are using the Twitter API in a incorrect way. From https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#track: you should seperate keywords with "," for logical OR and with " " for logical AND

Comment: @Salo: So, if I want AND, do you mean that this should work: keywords = ['data','information']
track = "".join(keywords)

Comment: @Salo: I checked OR: track = ",".join(keywords). It works. But AND does not work: track = "".join(keywords)

Comment: you have to join them with a <space> so this: " " and not this "". If you join them with an empty string they will be concatenated. Just try it out without joining by defining the string directly: "data,information" and "data information"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the Twitter API in a correct way.

From the [doc](http://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#track):

- For logical AND separate with space: `"data information"` == `" ".join(['data', 'information'])`
- For logical OR separate with comma: `"data,information"` == `",".join(['data', 'information'])`